# jQuery, webpacker & Rails 6 event listener

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, events, webpacker

I have a remote:true form built using SimpleForm that renders a JS file `create.js.erb`

```
// customers/create.js.erb
...
  $('#new_customer').trigger('customer:callback');
...
```

Meanwhile I have a listener in packs/customer/form.js that is included in the erb view using

`<%=javascript_pack_tag 'customers/form'%>`

```
// packs/customers/form.js
$(document).on('customer:callback', '#new_customer', function(data) {
  alert('Success');
});
```

The event listener is never triggered, however if I move the event listener to javascript/application.js it works. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the `trubolinks:load` event. This event is called the first time the page loads and every time on a turbolink visit.

So your code in `packs/customer/form.js` you should look like this:

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $("#new_customer").on("customer:callback", function(data){
    alert("Success");
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the code runs fine if I put the listener in application.js however, it does not if it's in the pack itself. I think I'm missing an import statement or something

Comment: I think i got it. 

Your `form.js` is in `packs/customer` but you've put `<%=javascript_pack_tag 'customerS/form'%>` is should be `<%=javascript_pack_tag 'customer/form'%>`.